# Django model does not update in celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to make a celery task that updates django model and sends email. The emails are sent properly but the model is not saved to the database. Any ideas why does it happen? Here is my sample task:

```
@app.task()
def send_invitation(company_id):
    users = User.objects.filter(company_id=company_id, user_email__invitation_sent=False)

    for user in users:
        user.user_email.invitation_sent = True
        user.save()
        send_email(user)
```

I have tried several saving options for example `user.user_email.save()` but when the task finishes, mails are sent but `invitation_sent` stays `False` and I can't figure out why this happens

Comment: is it possible your `users` query is empty?

Comment: It is not empty, I am getting the emails but status in database is not updated

Comment: Please include your models. They might provide some insight as to what the problem might be.

Comment: Try using update method on email instance like `user.user_email.update(invitation_sent=True)`

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am having a very similar problem and I cannot figure out why it is happening...

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're calling `save()` on the User model where as you are changing what appears to be the UserEmail (or something like it) model.

to fix this properly keep track of which model you want to save, so in your example:

```py
...
user.user_mail.invitation_sent = True
# call save on user_email instance
user.user_mail.save() #  <---- here
```

Though to be fair from your example you should definitely keep track of order of operations done with your emails. So send the email and if its successful, then mark it as such, don't say you did something before you do it.

Comment: As I have written in question I tried to user.user_email.save() but it did not save the changes aswell

Comment: was there an error or anything that you observed? what is the function `send_Email` doing ?

Comment: Task finishes without errors. Send_email od taking username etc from user and send it by sendgrid

Comment: @tookas92 Does the email have the correct user information?